# How to stop services on Travis CI running by default?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, yaml, travis-ci

The machine instances running for Travis CI [start some services by default](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MySQL) which are not useful to [my project](https://travis-ci.org/johnjohndoe/CampFahrplan/builds). Therefore I want to stop these services. My first idea was to use the following block in my *.travis.yml* to do so:

```yml
before_script:
  # Disable services enabled by default
  - sudo service mysql stop
  - sudo service postgresql stop
```

However, this was **successful** for one and **failed** for another machine:

```sh
$ sudo service mysql stop
mysql stop/waiting

$ sudo service postgresql stop
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.1 database server
   ...done.
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.2 database server
   ...done.
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
   ...done.
```

...

```sh
$ sudo service mysql stop    
stop: Unknown instance:

The command "sudo service mysql stop" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Another option is `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` but this could fail on a machine which started the process via the `service` command. Is there a try-catch I can use in the *.travis.yml* script?

Comment: Do you have links to builds where you've seen this happen?

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that using the mentioned `/etc/init.d/ ...` works more reliable. There are some warnings that one should use `sudo service ...` but I was not successful with those. So here is what I am running now:

```yml
language: android

jdk:
  - oraclejdk7
  - openjdk7

android:
  components:

    # All the build system components should be at the latest version
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-21.1.1
    - android-19

    # The libraries we can't get from Maven Central or similar
    - extra-android-support


notifications:
  email: true

before_script:

  # Disable services enabled by default
  # http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MySQL
  - sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
  - sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
  # The following did not work reliable
  # - sudo service mysql stop
  # - sudo service postgresql stop

  # Ensure Gradle wrapper is executable
  - chmod +x gradlew

  # Ensure signing configuration is present
  - mv app/gradle.properties.example app/gradle.properties

script:
  - ./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo service mysql stop`

I am using travis with laradock with mysql. And that command did the work for me.